# How to prevent the blurring of resized images (png/jpeg) in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, images, image-quality

I am new to Adobe illustrator, and I read that in Illustrator works on some vector technique means you can change the size of image without getting blurry.

I made my first logo and saved it as `PNG` format, but when I am increasing the size of image, its getting blurry.

So, **how can I save my image so when I increase its size, it doesn't get blurry?**

Answer (score 4):

You need to save it in a format that supports vector data. Choose one

- SVG, scalable vector graphics, if you need to show the results on the web then this is the obly realistic option.
- PDF, portable document format
- EPS, encapsulated PostScript
- AI, Adobe Illustrator

Or possibly but a bit pushing it:

- CDR
- DWG, DXF, STEP, IGES mainly lines only not much likelyhood of getting people to open these files.
- PS

Answer (score 1):

Any image in a **[raster](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics)** format (`.jpg` / `.png`) will pixelate when you zoom, no matter on which software you design it.

Comment: Hi Renee, welcome to GD.SE! I hope you don't mind, I added a link to raster format to better explain what you mean by non-scalable. Feel free to re-edit!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need .png format for web usage, your best option would be to build it in Illustrator to the dimensions you need, THEN save as .png. If you need to enlarge it later, you would go back to the original Illustrator file, enlarge it again (there would be no quality loss this way), then re-saving as .png.